# Issue with TCP Listener on .NET CF 2.0 on a Windows CE device

Tags: c#, windows, windows-ce, tcpclient

- **Device:** Motorola WT41N0 Windows CE 7.0
- **Device:** Motorola WT4090 Windows CE 5.0
- **Device Network:** All devices are connected to our Cisco Wireless system
- **.NET Framework:** .NET 2.0 CF

**Background**

I am trying to make a TCP listener on the mobile device to respond to TCP message request from a server application. For testing purposes I have the application respond to a message that starts with "reply" and will simply send a message back with the current time and close.

**Problem**

A small number of devices will stop responding to message requests making me think that there is something wrong with the method I am trying receive TCP messages on the device. I have ran tests where I have the server application send TCP messages while to device roams different wireless access points and it will always recover flawlessy during my tests. I am leading to think that there is a problem on how I have the device receive messages.

#### Windows CE Device Code (Server)

```
public void Receiver(int port)
{
    Thread ct = new Thread(
     new ThreadStart(
        delegate()
        {
            // Create the listener and start it
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(port);
            listener.Start();

            // Main listen loop
            while (true)
            {
                // Try to connect client
                try
                {
                    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                    client.NoDelay = true;

                    // Get the client stream
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

                    // Decode the TCP message
                    try
                    {
                        string request = sr.ReadLine();

                        if (request.StartsWith("reply"))
                        {
                            sw.WriteLine("reply|");
                            sw.WriteLine("time" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                            sw.Flush();
                            sw.Close();
                            sr.Close();
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        if (client.Client.Connected == true)
                        {
                            client.Close();
                            listener.Stop();
                            listener.Start();
                        }
                    }

                    client.Close();

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
        }));

    ct.IsBackground = true;
    ct.Start();
}
```

#### Server Code (Client)

`public void SendMessage(string ip_address, string port, string message)
{
    // Variables
    string request = "";

    try
    {
        TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();

        Client = new TcpClient(ip_address, Convert.ToInt32(port));

        Client.NoDelay = true;
        Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        Client.SendTimeout = 1000;
        StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(Client.GetStream());
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Client.GetStream());

        Writer.WriteLine(message);
        Writer.Flush();

        request = sr.ReadToEnd();
        new_message = request;

        //Close Connection
        Client.Close();
        Writer.Close();
        sr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {

    }
}`

#### Further Explanation

I know that at some point it will stop listening on that port and throw back an error station that the machine actively refused the connection.

The "server" code as it stands now is simply called by Receiver(9000). It will also create a background thread that is on a while loop that will sit and wait at the "TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();" .

When I use the "client" code to send a TCP message the server code will run through and wait for another connection attempt.

I have used this code in a simulation with two desktop pcs where the following is set up.

PC1 (Server) - Its just is to wait until it receives a message and quickly respond back, close connection, and wait for another connection

PC2 (Client) - Send messages repeatedly, receive the response message and close the connection.

With that test in mind I had it run for over a week with out issues. I even ran the same test with the device docked to power without issue. So what I am thinking is that since the device is in a wireless environment it needs to be able to recover from disconnects. So I guess my question is if the device is to lose wireless and gain it back will the "server" be able to recover correctly. The only other thing I can think of is to monitor the thread somehow and recreate a new listener thread if it fails.

Comment: Log your exceptions so you can see what is going wrong.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, and without a precise explanation of what the code's doing, it will be nearly impossible to say what the problem actually is. Disabling Nagle (i.e. `NoDelay=true`) is generally a bad idea (especially on mobile networks), but may or may not be related to what you're seeing (whatever that actually is...I'm having trouble reconciling the statements _"will stop responding"_ and _"will always recover flawlessy"_, which seem to directly contradict each other).

Comment: Ok I just added more explanation to my problem.